# Asset precompilation fails after rails upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, asset-pipeline

I just upgraded from Rails 4.0.4 to 4.1.8, and when I push to our staging server on Heroku, I get the following error

```
Removing jquery-rails (3.0.4)
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
       /tmp/build_6e5605f8ccbbe1dcb495bb63b761220d/config/initializers/puma_database_connection.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_6e5605f8ccbbe1dcb495bb63b761220d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
       /tmp/build_6e5605f8ccbbe1dcb495bb63b761220d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport
       /tmp/build_6e5605f8ccbbe1dcb495bb63b761220d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
```

When I run assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development, it works fine

Any advice?